# threading through a vector of functions

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of functions `(def my-func [a b c d])`. Each function takes the output of the last function as the input. I want to thread an input through them, how do I do that?

How do I get to the following form `(-> in a b c d)`?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`comp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp) but be aware it executes the functions right to left

```
((comp d c b a) 10)
```

or

```
((apply comp my-fns) 10)
```

will pass 10 to the first function, the result to the next function and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution Smith.

Comment: You are welcome.  There is an other function, [`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt) that takes a number of functions as arguments and applies the arguments to each function returning a vector of results `((juxt + - * /) 3 2) => [5 1 6 3/2]`

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the `reduce` function:

```
(def fns [inc inc inc])
(reduce (fn [v f] (f v)) 10 fns)
```

Comment: Thanks dAni, thats a wonderful way !

Comment: This reminds me of what @fogus was talking about in the [Thrush in Clojure](http://blog.fogus.me/2010/09/28/thrush-in-clojure-redux/)